# How to display video in laravel view

Tags: php, video, laravel-5.4

I am using laravel 5.4 i need to show one video in my product detail page but the video not displayed properly..

This is my view

```
@foreach($detail_videos as $video)
               <video width="100" height="100" controls class="thumb" data-full="{{ asset($video) }}">
                 <source src="{{ asset($video) }}">
               </video>
               @endforeach
```

In my controller i give like this

```
  $detail_dir_videos = 'uploads/products/videos/'.$getProduct->id;
      $detail_dir_videos_files = array_slice(scandir($detail_dir_videos), 2);
      $detail_videos = [];
      foreach($detail_dir_videos_files as $detail_dir_videos_file){
        $detail_videos[] = $detail_dir_videos.'/'.$detail_dir_videos_file;
      }
 return view('pages.product_detail', ['videos'=>$videos,'detail_videos'=>$detail_videos ])
```

Now the video is not displaying in my view can any please help me out to resolve this..

Comment: please post the output of this variable $detail_dir_videos_files and also what is being shown in the html in the videos place

Comment: This is the output of the variable $detail_dir_videos_files  `["vid_59106c1931d29.wmv"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edit this code and check

```
$detail_videos = [];
      foreach($detail_dir_videos_files as $detail_dir_videos_file){
        $detail_videos= $detail_dir_videos.'/'.$detail_dir_videos_file;
      }
```

Comment: ERROR : Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: in this line or in the view??

Comment: {{ $detail_videos }} in your view to see if you are getting array or normal name.

Comment: Sorry i didnot understand what you meant to say

Comment: `@foreach($detail_videos as $video)
               <video width="100" height="100" controls class="thumb" data-full="{{ $video }}">
                 <source src="{{ $video }}">
               </video>
               @endforeach`  This is inside my view

Comment: sorry, do one thing print this $detail_videos inside your controller after that foreach and tell me the output

Comment: This is the output when i print that variable `uploads/products/videos/2/vid_591064567b027.wmv`

Comment: ok tell me one thing now. will there be multiple videos or just one? and where is this variable coming from the videos that you are senfding?

 return view('pages.product_detail', ['videos'=>$videos,'detail_videos'=>$detail_videos ])

Comment: only one video that $video have this following code ` $videos = Product::where('is_active','!=','0')->orderBy('created_at','desc')->limit(2)->get();
        $videos->map(function ($product) {
        $directory = 'uploads/products/videos/'.$product->id;
          if (is_dir($directory)) {
            $files = scandir ($directory);
            $img_file = $directory.'/'.$files[2];
            $product['front_video'] = $img_file;
          }
      });`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143826/discussion-between-karthiga-and-exprator).